# Power BI dataset permissions: Can't display the visual

Tags: powerbi, permissions, powerbi-datasource

Recently we started experimenting with having end-users create their own Power BI reports. We've created several datasets in a Power BI workspace for them to consume in their reports and they upload their reports to their own personal workspace. However, when they use them, there are visuals that can't be displayed.

User 1 consumed the datasets and used a local Excel source to create a report. The report uses mixed mode, which makes me believe that the Excel data is saved in the report, with a DirectQuery connection to the datasets. However, Power BI complains that no gateway is installed for the Excel files. The report doesn't display any visuals (even to people who have access to the datasets).

[Report with visuals that can't be displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viklE.png)

User 2 consumed the datasets and used a Sharepoint Excel source. They can see the visuals and I can see them as well (we both have access to the datasets; I do not have access to the Sharepoint site). They shared their reports with User 3 who does have access to the Sharepoint, but is not allowed to access the datasets. User 3 can't see the visuals.

We gave User 2 permission to Read and Build the datasets, which makes me believe they can use the data in a report and share that report with another user, without the other user needing to have access to the datasets themselves. User 2 gave permission to User 3 to view the report in their workspace, so everything should be set for User 3 to see the report, but still it doesn't work. I feel we're missing something very obvious. Also, regarding User 1's report: should it be possible to use datasets with other sources in mixed mode? I really hope somebody can shed some light on how this security model works, because a couple of days reading various articles on the matter didn't give me any new insights.